# How to configure \cref to write "Appendix A" instead of "Chapter A" when referring to appendix?

Tags: cross-referencing, koma-script, appendices, cleveref

I want to configure `\cref` to write "Appendix A" instead of misleading "Chapter A".

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter}
    This is a test, represented in \cref{appendix:Test}.

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Test Appendix}
        The contents...\label{appendix:Test}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

The code above will create the following page:

[image: \cref referring to misleading target]

---

**Description of the issue:**

The problem now is: A potential reader won't understand that "Chapter A" is a part of the appendix. Therefore I would prefer to write something like "Appendix A" in the text.

**How can I configure `\cref` to write "Appendix A" instead of misleading "Chapter A" when labelling the target appendix with `\label{appendix:Random test appendix}`?**

`\cref` does such a great job for figures and tables, why not for appendices? In best case (like it already does for figures and tables), it should automatically detect if the `\cref` is placed at the beginning of a sentence (= "**A**ppendix A") or in the middle/end of a sentence (= "**a**ppendix A")...

How to configure that? :-)

Comment: The example does not use `\cref`. If the first letter should be uppercase use `\Cref`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\label[appendix]{...}` for each chapter label in the appendix or you can set `\crefalias{chapter}{appendix}` in the `appendices` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\xapptocmd\appendices{%
  \crefalias{chapter}{appendix}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
This is a test, represented in \cref{appendix:Test}. \Cref{appendix:Test} \ldots

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test}
  The contents \ldots
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Complex example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\xapptocmd\appendices{%
  \crefalias{chapter}{appendix}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
\begingroup
\raggedright
This is a test, represented in
  \cref{appendix:Test_A}.
  \Cref{appendix:Test_A}
  \ldots\par
This is a test, represented in
  \cref{appendix:Test_A,,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C}.
  \Cref{appendix:Test_A,,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C}
  \ldots\par
This is a test, represented in
  \cref{appendix:Test_A,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C}.
  \Cref{appendix:Test_A,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C}
  \ldots\par
This is a test, represented in
  \cref{appendix:Test_D,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C}.
  \Cref{appendix:Test_D,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C} \ldots\par
This is a test, represented in
  \cref{appendix:Test_A,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C,appendix:Test_E,appendix:Test_F}.
  \Cref{appendix:Test_A,appendix:Test_B,appendix:Test_C,appendix:Test_E,,appendix:Test_F}
  \ldots\par
\endgroup

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_A}
  The contents \ldots
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_B}
  The contents \ldots
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_C}
  The contents \ldots
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_D}
  The contents \ldots
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_E}
  The contents \ldots
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test_F}
  The contents \ldots
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If the appendix is not followed by "normal" chapters you can use the switch `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
This is a test, represented in \cref{appendix:Test}. \Cref{appendix:Test} \ldots

\appendix
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test}
  The contents \ldots
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

or without package `appendices`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addpart{Appendices}%
}{}{\Patch Failed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
This is a test, represented in \cref{appendix:Test}. \Cref{appendix:Test} \ldots

\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test}
The contents \ldots
\end{document}
```

If the TOC entry for the appendices page should have the same style as chapter entries use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\xapptocmd\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addchaptertocentry{}{Appendices}%
  \addpart*{Appendices}%
}{}{\Patch Failed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
This is a test, represented in \cref{appendix:Test}. \Cref{appendix:Test} \ldots

\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix}\label{appendix:Test}
The contents \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess Lehmanns would print your book »250 ready-made code examples for KOMA-script«. At least I'd buy it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a solution that works well with `hyperref` and generates 'Appendix' and 'Appendices' words automatically.

After loading `cleveref`, use this code in the preamble

```
\crefformat{app}{appendix #2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{app}{appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{app}{appendices #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{app}{appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
```

Which defines how appendices referencing will appear when using `\cref`. **Use this at the middle of sentences.**

Also, add this

```
\Crefformat{app}{Appendix #2#1#3}
\Crefrangeformat{app}{Appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\Crefmultiformat{app}{Appendices #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\Crefrangemultiformat{app}{Appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
```

Which defines how appendices referencing will appear when using `\Cref`. **Use this at the beginning of sentences.**

Both codes will customize `\cref` and `\Cref` commands to refer to appendices in very elegant and generalized fashion. **When you define a label for an appendix, use** `\label[app]{<Appendix_Label>}`

This solution does not detect if we are at the beginning or the middle of a sentence. Thus, you must use decide manually whether to use `\Cref` or `\cref`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}


\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[notref, notcite, color]{showkeys}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{app}{appendix #2#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{app}{appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{app}{appendices #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{app}{appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}

\Crefformat{app}{Appendix #2#1#3}
\Crefrangeformat{app}{Appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
\Crefmultiformat{app}{Appendices #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\Crefrangemultiformat{app}{Appendices #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{, #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4 to #5#2#6}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular Chapter}

Using \texttt{$\backslash$Cref}

\noindent \Cref{Appendix_A}

\noindent \Cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C}

\noindent\Cref{Appendix_D,,Appendix_E,,Appendix_F}

\noindent \Cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_I}

\noindent \Cref{Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_G,Appendix_H,,Appendix_I}

\noindent \Cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_G,Appendix_H,Appendix_I}

\vspace{\baselineskip}


\noindent Using \texttt{$\backslash$cref}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_A}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_D,,Appendix_E,,Appendix_F}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_I}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_G,Appendix_H,,Appendix_I}

\noindent Test sentence \cref{Appendix_A,Appendix_B,Appendix_C,Appendix_E,Appendix_F,Appendix_G,Appendix_H,Appendix_I}

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Appendix A}
        The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_A}
     \chapter{Appendix B}
        The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_B}
     \chapter{Appendix C}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_C}
     \chapter{Appendix D}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_D}
     \chapter{Appendix E}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_E}
     \chapter{Appendix F}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_F}
     \chapter{Appendix G}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_G}
     \chapter{Appendix H}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_H}
     \chapter{Appendix I}
    The contents...\label[app]{Appendix_I}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```